# Get value from textbox input without ng-repeat

Tags: python, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS.

I want to get value from input text without ng-repeat where the value is from Python.

Value from Python:

```
{{user.id}}
```

My text input:

```
<form ng-submit="SendHttpPostData()">
  <p><input type="text" ng-model="user" value="{{user.id}}"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My problem is:

1. The value of `user.id` doesn't display in input text.
2. I get undefined result when click Submit button.

Comment: You should set the user object to the python value in your angular controller if possible.

Comment: doesn't make sense setting `ng-model` to be the whole `user` object and not a property of that object. Otherwise it's not clear what your problem is

Comment: James Buck can you give some example..

Comment: charlietfl : I've edit my question

Comment: ng-model should be user.id then it will give output

Comment: I've already use ng-model = "user.id", but I get an error : user is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Angular, by default, will not read the `value` attribute of an input when initializing data bindings. However, you can write a directive which will do this for you:

```
app.directive('value', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel)
        return;

      var val = attrs.value || element.val() || element.text();
      ngModel.$setViewValue(val);
      ngModel.$render();
    }
  };
});
```

This will ensure that whenever the `value` attribute appears together with `ng-model`, it will be used to initialize the bindings. See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6y2XDY9RAeBaKeKFjWHB) for a demo.

---

However, please note that **this is not the recommended way of passing data to Angular from the backend**. Generally, it is best to write a JSON API endpoint and load the data into the client-side using `$http` or `$resource`.